# Solving exact equations In ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve
$$(x^2-y^2+3x-y)dx+(x^2-y^2+x-3y)dy=0$$

How to convert this into an exact differential? What will be the integrating factor?

Comment: well its already in M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy so just use partial derivative test

Comment: but the partial differential are not equal.so we have to convert into exact DE

Answer (score 1):

Variation of parameters:
\begin{align*}
  M(x,y) &= (x^2-y^2+3x-y)u(x+y) \\
  N(x,y) &= (x^2-y^2+x-3y)u(x+y) \\
  \partial_y M &= (x^2-y^2+3x-y)u'(x+y)+(-2y-1)u(x+y) \\
  \partial_x N &= (x^2-y^2+x-3y)u'(x+y)+(2x+1)u(x+y) \\
\end{align*}

Take $\partial_y M=\partial_x N$

\begin{align*}
  (x+y)u'(x+y) &= (x+y+1)u(x+y) \\
  tu'(t) &= (t+1)u(t) \tag{$t=x+y$} \\
  u(t) &= Cte^{t} \\
  u(x+y) &= (x+y)e^{x+y} \tag{$C=1$} \\
\end{align*}

Now

\begin{align*}
  M(x,y) &= (x+y)[x^2-y^2+2(x-y)+(x+y)]e^{x+y} \\
  &= \partial_{x} [(x-y)(x+y)^2e^{x+y}] \\
  N(x,y) &= (x+y)[x^2-y^2+2(x-y)-(x+y)]e^{x+y} \\
  &= \partial_{y} [(x-y)(x+y)^2e^{x+y}] \\
  0 &= [(x-y)(x+y)^2e^{x+y}]'
\end{align*}

$$\fbox{$(x-y)(x+y)^2e^{x+y}=k$}$$